# SE sites for application usage

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, mobile-web

I realize that some frameworks have their own SE sites (e.g. Android, Windows Phone) and even some application frameworks (e.g. Drupal), but as I understand it, most application usage questions seem to get directed as follows (SE site, if any, in parentheses):

- Applications used for software development (Stack Overflow)
- Other Desktop Applications (Super User)
- Other Web Applications (Web Applications)
- Other Mobile Applications (platform specific homes)
- Other Tablet Applications (platform specific homes)

My related questions are:

- Is my characterization of the above mapping correct?
- While the above topology is understandable from a historical perspective, can you point to any substantive SE discussion of whether it makes sense today?
- Specifically, what are the benefits of having distinct sites for Desktop/Web/Mobile/Tablet application usage?
- When application communities push for their own SE site through Area 51, are there any common reasons given for why the corresponding "generic" SE site is not adequate?

Comment: There was a [discussion about tablets on SU](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5045/please-vote-on-proposed-changes-to-our-policy-on-tablet-computers), but the [FAQ doesn't seem to have been updated](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic)...

Comment: Android Enthusiasts and Ask Different I believe cover the respective mobile and tablet applications for the specific OS's, but I may be interpreting the scopes incorrectly.